# How to tail stdout or any of the standard streams?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, terminal, stdout

I'm trying to understand how standard streams work in Linux, specifically how I can capture say, `stdout` directly from my terminal with something like *tail*. Since everything in Linux is a file, isn't it possible to simply do a `tail -f /dev/stdout`?

So to test this, I wrote a trivial program:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    while (1) {
        printf("This takes advantage of stdout\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then in a separate terminal I did a `tail -f stdout`, but nothing is printed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `./yourprogram | tail -f`?

Comment: `stdout` is like a virtual file. It only exists internally inside your program; other (C) programs (maybe running at the same time) have a different `stdout`.

Comment: Stdout of which program did you hope to capture this way? There are many processes running and a Linux box is not an expert mind reader to know exactly which one you wanted. Perhaps a Mac OS X box would do a better job...

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? `tail -f /dev/stdout` and `some_program | tail -f` are valid commands pipelines, but it is not clear what useful function they would serve...

Comment: @SergeyL. I didn't see any output with that.

Comment: @pmg I thought that /dev/stdout was just a symlink that points to the current running process whatever that may be, so I thought it would just print out everything being sent to stdout. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each [*process*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its *own* [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). So you need to capture the standard output of some running process. The usual way is to make a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), but you may also [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) the stdout to some file.

Learn more about [tee(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html). Read some [bash scripting tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial)

A typical use might be thru [batch(1)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) and a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document); I often do

```
batch << EOJ
  make >& _make.out
EOJ
```

<sup>the `>&` is a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)-ism or a [zsh](http://zsh.org/)-ism redirecting both stdout and stderr.</sup>

Then in a separate terminal -or even in the same terminal, after the `batch` sequence above- (in the same current directory)

```
tail -f _make.out
```

This enables me to see the progression of e.g. a long-lasting compilation (of course I can interrupt with <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd> the `tail -f` command without harming the compilation). YMMV.
Read also [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Actually, `/dev/stdout` (notice that `stdout` alone means nothing particular to the shell) is a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `/proc/self/fd/1` . Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

BTW, in your C code, take the habit of calling [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before any important syscall like `sleep` or `fork` (your code don't need it because *stdout* on *terminal* is *line* buffered but might be differently buffered when *stdout* is *not* a tty). Read [stdout(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html). Terminals are weird beasts, read [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

#### addenda

To test in your *C* or *C++* code if `stdout` is a terminal, use [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html), i.e.

```
 if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
     stdout_is_a_terminal();
```

Notice that *stdout* could be a pipe or a file (then of course the above test would fail).

To write to the terminal, use `/dev/tty` (see [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)). To write on the console use `/dev/console` (see [console(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console.4.html)...). For system logging, learn about [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) and e.g. [rsyslogd(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rsyslogd.8.html).